# Обмен данными между несколькими Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, камера, робототехника

Задача создать стек из 4 плат Ras PI, к 3-м из них подключить по штатной CSI камере, а четвертая должна собрать данные предварительной обработки от каждой платы с камерой и нечто общее посчитать (не суть вопроса что именно). Работать должно в реальном времени с разрешением HD и со скоростью не менее 40 FPS (что одна плата с одной камерой вполне позволяет). 
Плата с камерой отдает не сами изображения, а данные о выделенных из них контурах (то есть трафик относительно небольшой, не более 2% от размера изображения). 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста два момента:

1. Среда коммуникаций - Ethernet, WI-FI или Bluetooth - если Eth то HUB
   еще где-то надо пристроить, если это мобильное устройство (коптер,
   например) тогда даже не знаю как с хабом быть... Bluetooth 4.1 очень
   привлекательно но никогда не работал - кто-нибудь посоветует
   библиотеку чтобы настроить коннект для группы плат? ничего не
   нашел... если wifi то тоже непросто - одна из плат тогда будет
   точкой доступа, а нигде не написано можно ли на RasPI так...
2. Протокол обмена (когда уже есть среда коммуникаций) - самое первое,
   что приходит в голову, это 0MQ - вероятно это и правильно, но может
   у кого-то есть опыт подобных вещей и другие рекомендации? Удастся ли
   с помощью 0MQ добиться синхронности +-2 кадра, при условии что все
   остальное - сеть и платы - работает идеально?

Comment: "одна из плат тогда будет будет точкой доступа, а нигде не написано можно ли на RasPI так..." -- [ну почему же нигде](https://gist.github.com/Lewiscowles1986/fecd4de0b45b2029c390).

Comment: @D-side спасибо, это круто что с кодом! Надо было не спеки мне вычитывать а сразу код искать...

Comment: На самом деле нет, я просто сразу начал искать способ подъёма SoftAP ("программной точки доступа") на RPi3, по ключевому слову `hostapd` (т. к. под Linux SoftAP поднимаются именно им). Это не первая ссылка, но наиболее, скажем так, нейтральная :) Баш что в русскоязычном сообществе, что в англоязычном, одинаковый :)